# How to guarantee a row-level unique constraint in a transactional service method?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, transactions

I have some business checks in my service layer, where I check it with some queries and conditions.

they can not do in the database layer as a unique or checks. but in concurrency two request pass the check and make mistake in my data . 
the problem is : i take goods serial from user controls , and i check goods serial with database if it's not exists in the database let it to save the record otherwise throw a exception . 
the image help to understand the problem better :
http://pasteboard.co/gPE0BRlRK.jpg

we can use pessimistic lock on hibernate but if we don't have any record in database with number A100 for example checks pass and two transaction commit in database .

the save Method is Here :

```
@Override
    public Long save(Product entity) {
        if (!isUniqueForSave(entity))
            throw new ApplicationException(saveUniqueError);
        return super.save(entity); 
    }
```

and the Method isUniqueForSave :

```
 private boolean isUniqueForSave(Product entity) {
            return iProductRepository.isUniqueForSave(entity);
        }
```

and the query in DAO layer is in this Method :

```
public boolean isUniqueForSave(Product entity) {

        Session session = getSession();
        String hql = "select  c from " + domainClass.getName() + " c " 
                    + " where c.ProductNumber      = :productNumber "
                    + " and   c.item.id = :itemId "
                    + " and   c.deleted        = 0 ";



        if (entity.getId() != null && entity.getId() > 0)
            hql += " and c.id != "+entity.getId();

        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        query.setParameter("productNumber ", entity.getProductNumber());
        query.setParameter("itemId ", entity.getItem().getId());

        List<Product> productsList = query.list();
        if(productsList .size() > 1)
            return false;
        else if(productsList .size() == 0)
            return true;

        Product product=  productsList .get(0);
        if(entity.getOldItem() != null && product.getId().equals(entity.getOldItem().getId()))
            return true;

        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to save an Order with a unique id? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: i want to save a goods, goods serial has to unique and i can not doing it on database , i have to do that on business check in service layer

Comment: i do that as a method that run a query like this : select * from goods e where e.goodsNumber=:goodsNumber and goosCode=:goodsCode and e.delete=0

Comment: if the select have result exception return to the user , if it's not the record will save to database

Comment: I don;t know what a "good serial" is. It's something that specific to your Domain Model which only you and your team member know.

Comment: good serial is an unique , for example you have an application that manage mobile shop , you have to manage serial numbers unique, there is already a Samsung S6 with serial A100 in the world .

Comment: Like the unique constraint on that the `product_key` column of the `Product` table?

Comment: exactly like that but for some field and conditions it's can not in the table , i have to check it on service side

Comment: Sorry, but your request is way too vague for me to give a proper answer. This question needs a lot of context to answer it properly.

Comment: this is not vague , if you in my situation and in your business application want to some check in service layer , like unique , what are you doing in that situation ?

Comment: There are many options. I can use a UUID. I can call a database sequence and fetch a unique identifier.

Comment: the filed i mentioned it before , it's taking from user

Comment: If I have a 3rd part value that needs to be unique, I can save it in a unique column. If you can't do that, it's going to be difficult to guarantee unicity.

Comment: i read your post about transaction isolation and optimistic and pessimistic lock in your blog , my database is oracle and i can't use read uncommited , really how can i solve it ?

Comment: You need to post the exact schema you have, the service methods, and the actual requirement so that it's easy to understand. I still don;t understand what you really need.

Comment: i edit the post and put service methods in it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is vulnerable to SQL Injection. You really want to get that fixed too!

The problem here is that you want to guarantee that no other transaction will sneak in and add a `Product` with the same filtering criteria.

Optimistic locking can only help you if there's already an existing row in the database. Therefore, in your case, optimistic locking works only when the row is marked as deleted.

However, you want this check to work even if there's no record in the database upon the query execution. In this case, you need to use [`SERIALIZABLE`](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-acid-and-database-transactions/) since it prevents Phantom Reads and also Lost Updates.

So, you need to annotate the current transaction as [`SERIALIZABLE`](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-transaction-isolation-levels-in-enterprise-java/).

Comment: Read the articles that I provided in the answer. For a more detailed explanation, you can check out my [High-Performance Java Persistence](https://leanpub.com/high-performance-java-persistence) book as well.